# Laptop battery doesn't charge after 60%

Tags: power-management, laptop, hp, battery

Details:

Laptop Hp 15-bs 145 tu (2 years old)

ubuntu version 18.04 LTS

Once charge reaches 60%, it keeps on charging discharging each minute.
Also, around 20% it automatically shuts down without giving any warning of low power.

I already tried calibrating (draining battery to 0% and charging while it is turned off till it shows white light). But even in that case, once it reaches 60%, white and red light keeps changing.

(white light = fully charged, red light = charging).

What should I do ? Should I replace battery ?

Comment: After two years, it could already be the battery indeed, although batteries typically keep operating decently for about three years.

Comment: Yeah, that's what confusing me !! When battery is between 20% to 60%, it looks good, but in other cases, it works strange !

Comment: Could also be a BIOS setting.

Comment: @vanadium please explain more (in detail)

Comment: Sounds like a failing battery, my prediction is it would be dead by a couple of months or so.

Comment: Rereading, that is probably not the issue. In my bios, computer can be set to load battery only to 80%. Very likely, it is a failing battery. Replace battery, or just use continuously on AC power if feasible for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like some of the battery cells might be dead, which stands to reason after two years. If you want to confirm it, try with another OS or another distribution to rule out a potential bug - but it doubt that a bug is the case.

Also, you battery is likely a lithium-ion battery, if so avoid completely discharging the battery:
[https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/five-apps/five-tips-for-extending-lithium-ion-battery-life/#:~:text=4%3A%20Avoid%20completely%20discharging%20lithium%2Dion%20batteries&text=Only%20battery%20analyzers%20with%20the,that%20condition%20for%20several%20months](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/five-apps/five-tips-for-extending-lithium-ion-battery-life/#:%7E:text=4%3A%20Avoid%20completely%20discharging%20lithium%2Dion%20batteries&text=Only%20battery%20analyzers%20with%20the,that%20condition%20for%20several%20months).

The idea of it being good to completely discharge batteries comes from older generations of batteries (different technology) and even tough it isn't necessary to charge occasionally, it can for some batteries cause problems to do a complete discharge. The general advice I would give, is just charge whenever it's convenient, and when the computer goes into stand by, don't drain it further, you gain nothing by it, and if the battery is bad you risk doing damage.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I replaced the battery, and it worked. 
Commenting here in. case anyone else faces the same issue.